# Restoring PostgreSQL database without having a dump

Tags: ubuntu, restore

My hoster upgraded my Ubuntu server and it's not booting any more. The only way I can access my data any more is in read mode via a rescue environment (SSH shell).

I am running a postgres 9.1 installation on the crashed server. I am not able to start the postgres server in the rescue environment. I also do not have a dababase dump created with *pg_dump*.

However, I was able to copy the whole **/var/lib/postgresql** folder to a new machine . I installed Postgres 9.1 on this machine. Afertwards I replaced the **/var/lib/postgresql** with my old files.

When I start the postgres server, I get something like "incorrect checksum in control file".

I there any way to restore the database content **without using pg_dump** (since I don't have a current dump and I am not able to run it on the defective machine).